# How to fix "Git fetch --prune" fatal error?

Tags: git

I'm having some problems to delete local branch from a repo which does not exists any more.

```
William@WILLIAM /c/xampp/htdocs/apeppers (master)
$ git fetch --prune
fatal: repository 'https://williamcalderipe@bitbucket.org/williamcalderipe/myRepo.git/' not found
```

I want to remove that '(master)'

```
William@WILLIAM /c/xampp/htdocs/apeppers (master)
$ git push origin :master
Password for 'https://williamcalderipe@bitbucket.org':
error: unable to delete 'master': remote ref does not exist
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://williamcalderipe@bitbuck

William@WILLIAM /c/xampp/htdocs/apeppers (master)
$ git branch -d master
error: Cannot delete the branch 'master' which you are currently on.
```

Comment: Does master branch still exist on bitbucket? Have u tried to switch to another branch and then delete local master?

Comment: `git remote rm origin`

Answer (score 1):

You need to checkout a different branch before deleting a local branch:

```
git checkout some_other_branch
git branch -D master
```

You should use `-D` instead of `-d`, since the remote does not exist it doesn't really matter.

I'm not sure why you would want to delete the branch master, so please, before you do so, run the following and save the output, so in case you regret anything it will be much easier to undo:

```
git checkout master
git rev-parse HEAD
```

And save the output.

Comment: I can't use checkout because my repo does not exist any more. Any idea what to do now?

Comment: @Cald That does not make sense. If the repo does not exist, neither does `master` nor could you do any push at all (Git would fail with `not a repository`). You might not be aware that Git is a [DVCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control_system), and you have a local copy of the complete repository. So your remote might not exist anymore, but obviously your local repo is still there.

Comment: You can run `git remote -v` to see what your remote is called (usually `origin`), and remove it with `git remote remove <name>`. Having no remote means you cannot run any of the following commands: `git push`, `git pull`, `git fetch`. All other commands should work properly (but they should even if you don't delete it). If you're still having problems with commands other than these 3, please paste the commands and the output.